# openlayers 3 and geolocation without HTTPS

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers, geolocation, position, http

I am creating an application where user can locate himself on map. the code is working fine in local development environment, but when i deploy it over server(IIS) the code won't work. here is code :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

<script src="/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/ol.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
  #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
  }
</style>

<title>location</title>

</head>

  <body>

  <div id="map" class="map"></div>

  <div id="location"></div>

  <button id='buttonx' text='click'>Locate</button>    

  <script type="text/javascript">

   var mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
        className: 'custom-mouse-position',
        target: document.getElementById('location'),
        coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(5),
        undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
    });


   view = new ol.View({
      projection: 'EPSG:3857',
      center: [3800510.28980, 1160303.68138],
      zoom: 14
    });

    var layertileformap = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
        controls: ol.control.defaults({
            attribution: false
        }).extend([mousePositionControl]),
        target: document.getElementById('map'),
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        view: view,
        layers: [layertileformap]
    });
    var geolocation = new ol.Geolocation({
        projection: map.getView().getProjection(),
        tracking: false,
        trackingOptions: {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            maximumAge: 5000
        }
    });
    var button = document.getElementById('buttonx');
    var handleGetPosition = function (e) {
        var trackingwasalreadyon = geolocation.getTracking();
        alert('Track : ' + trackingwasalreadyon);
        console.log('Track : ' + trackingwasalreadyon);
        if (trackingwasalreadyon) {
            geolocation.setTracking(false);
        } else {
            geolocation.setTracking(true); getPosition();
        }
    };
    button.addEventListener('click', handleGetPosition, false);
    button.addEventListener('touchstart', handleGetPosition, false);
    function getPosition() {
        var accuracyFeature = new ol.Feature();
        geolocation.on('change:accuracyGeometry', function () {
            accuracyFeature.setGeometry(geolocation.getAccuracyGeometry());
        });
        var positionFeature = new ol.Feature();
        positionFeature.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
            image:new ol.style.Icon({
                anchor: [0.5, 100],
                anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
                opacity: 1.0,
                src: "/Content/geolocate.png",
            })
        }));
        geolocation.on('change', function () {
            alert('locaCalling');
            var pos = geolocation.getPosition();
            positionFeature.setGeometry(pos ?
                new ol.geom.Point(pos) : null);
            view.setCenter(pos);
            view.setZoom(19);
        });

        new ol.layer.Vector({
            map: map,
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
                features: [accuracyFeature, positionFeature]
            })
        });
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

After a lot of research i found this [link](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins) which summarize that the location feature will work over HTTPS only.

```
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins
```

I just want to ask do we have any process to bypass the feature.

Comment: "Proxy server" is 3 letters too short to be a comment by itself, but that's what you need. You can either run one locally or see if you can get one online (using a VPN will do the trick, but there are other ways). Important: make sure you trust whoever gives you an https proxy, since they can read your encrypted info (they decrypt it and then re-encrypt it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply can't bypass https.

It's a mandatory requirement (with exception of localhost usage) as stated by the [Geolocation API documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API) (an HTML5 API implemented in all browsers), at least for Firefox and Chrome (see browsers [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API#Browser_compatibility) from MDN).